# Twitterboostrap popover on a button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

is it possible to put a popover on a button (submit button) so when over over you get the pop over and when clicked it still does its job of submitting a form? all the examples I have seen require it to be a link.

does any one have any js fiddels of a pop over on a button, not a link styled to be a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example: http://jsbin.com/akuhun/1

HTML:

```
<form id="aform" action="http://google.com/">
    <input type="submit" class="btn" data-toggle="popover" data-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?" data-original-title="A Title">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").hover(function () {
    $(this).popover('show');
},function () {
    $(this).popover('hide');
});
```